# How to check whether input array is in consecutive manner or not?

Tags: java, java-me

I want to check whether my input array is consecutive or not?
In my application user can give input 1,6,7 then it returns false and if user input 3,4,5,6 then it returns true.
how can I do this in J2ME?

Comment: this must be homework...

Comment: not getting your question Megha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is to write a loop that goes through each element in the array, starting from position zero to n-1 making sure that the value of the element at the next position (if any, you have to check boundaries all the time), is exactly the value of the element at the current position+1. The moment you find the condition to be false; you return false; if you don't ever find a condition where the condition is not true, you can return true at the end of the loop.

That's a very good exercise for you. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through array and see if the next element (if exist) is exactly 1 greater than the previous one(if exist), if not return false, true otherwise at the end